# Help identifying 4-pin 2.5 mm pitch wire to board connector with latch

Tags: identification, connector

I'm looking for a 4-pin version of this 5-pin cable connector. It is for the Bluetooth module on a LiFePo4 BMS. You can see both PCB connectors in the 3rd picture. 2.5 mm pitch.

Can anyone identify the specific connector name?

[image: 5 pin latch]
*Figure 1: 5-pin latching connector, end view*

---

[image: 5 pin latch top]
*Figure 2: 5-pin latching connector, top view*

---

[image: 4 pin board side]
*Figure 3: 4-pin and 5-pin PCB latching connectors*

Comment: 2.5mm or 2.54mm? 2.5mm is an oddball pitch, 2.54mm (0.1'') is super-standard. Measure center-to-center between the outmost pins on the widest 6 pin connector, then divide by 6.

Answer (score 1):

[My connector identification utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=wire_to_board_conn&o=discrete_1row_latch_w2b_conn&f=discrete_1row_latch_w2b_conn_2p5&s=XA) found these possible matches:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- JST - XA
- Molex - Mini-Lock

Of those, the [JST XA](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=272) looks most likely.

Comment: Thanks Davide. I should have included the word 'pitch' after 2.5 mm. Edited original post. I looked at just about every JST connector I could find. Will look at Molex now.

Comment: That leaves 2:  * MANUF. - SERIES
* JST - XA
* Molex - Mini-Lock

Comment: BTW: thanks for creating that website/tool. Amazing amount of information there!

Comment: Thank you. It's a work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a "clone" of your connector. [2.50mm Pitch XHB crimp style connector](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/2-50mm-Pitch-XHB-crimp-style_1600456339487.html?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.normal_offer.d_image.770e64adHApnEM).

Your images look more like the [2.0mm pitch version](https://www.lhecn.com/a2005/) that I was looking for when I ran across your post. (mfg by Yeonho and TAIHUA)

2.0mm version image:
[image: A2005-PHB connector image]